# Does Air Europa require a tourist visa to Cuba?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, cuba, tourist-visas

Does Air Europa require you to have a tourist visa for Cuba to get on board or can I buy it at Havana Airport?

Comment: Is your nationality one of the ones that's allowed to get a visa on arrival? (That'll certainly make a difference!)

Comment: It totally does not depend on the airline, only on Cuba and your citizenship/residence country.

Comment: The airline *could* make a difference, to the extent that Cuban law and practice treat different airlines differently. And Cuba being Cuba I would not necessarily assume it works like most other countries in the world (where, indeed, the airline does not matter much) but I really don't know if it is actually the case.

Answer (score 3):

Air Europa would do what all airlines do - ensure you're legally permitted to visit the country (in this case, Cuba).

This would usually mean a check of your passport, nationality, and whether you require a visa before boarding - ie, whether or not you're able to get one on arrival in Havana.

This will depend entirely on Cuba's relationship with your country and whether or not they require you to have visas in advance.

You'll need to check with the relevant government department for your country, or one of the online visa check services. For example, [New Zealanders require a visa for entry to Cuba](http://cuba.visahq.com/requirements/New_Zealand/resident-United_States/).